# Internal cmake error while building trilinos on ubuntu 32bit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, fortran, trilinos

I'm trying to build the library trilinos on a 32bit ubuntu virtual machine. I wrote the following configuration script:

```
cmake \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:FILEPATH=./ \
-D Trilinos_ENABLE_ALL_OPTIONAL_PACKAGES:BOOL=OFF \
-D Trilinos_ENABLE_Anasazi:BOOL=ON \
-D Trilinos_ENABLE_Epetra:BOOL=ON \
-D Trilinos_ENABLE_EpetraEXt:BOOL=ON \
-D Trilinos_ENABLE_Triutils:BOOL=ON \
-D Trilinos_ENABLE_Belos:BOOL=ON \
-D Trilinos_ENABLE_Ifpack:BOOL=ON \
-D Trilinos_ENABLE_TESTS:BOOL=ON \
-D TPL_BLAS_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libblas.so.3 \
-D TPL_LAPACK_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 \
-D CMACKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON \
-D Trilinos_ENABLE_DEBUG:BOOL=ON \
-D CMACK_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=DEBUG \
-D Trilinos_ENABLE_EXPLICIT_INSTANTIATION:BOOL=ON \
../
```

When I execute it with the `ksh` command in the terminal, I get the following error:

> CMake Error: CMAKE_Fortran_Compiler not set, after EnableLanguage

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I don't know if i jave it installed or not, I've just installed ubuntu a few days ago

Comment: @AlexanderVogt, it solved my problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you do not have a Fortran compiler installed. This is why `cmake` cannot set `CMAKE_Fortran_Compiler` on its own, and requests you to manually specify one.

Since you are using Ubuntu, I would recommend using `gfortran` from the GCC suite. If you install the compiler from the repository, `cmake` should be fine.

You can install the compiler using

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```